# Switching addon domain to a primary domain

Tags: plesk, addon-domain

I have a dedicated server which currently serves up the following websites using Plesk 12 :

```
 primarydomain1.com
 |
 |-> addondomain1.com
 |-> addondomain2.com

 primarydomain2.com
```

What is the process for taking addondomain1.com and making it a primary domain (keeping the addondomain1.com domain name and all related databases and files intact).

I basically just want to move it out of addons and make it a top level domain.

Is it at all possible or is it better to just back everything up, delete it and re-install it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such feature in Plesk now.

Yes, it's better to manually backup files, mail files and databases, delete add-on domain, create subscription and manually restore all stuff.